# How to translate and resize a container simultaneously in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, animation

Im still a bit new to Flutter and was wondering if it is possible to have multiple animations taking place on a single widget.

I wish to resize and rescale my container simultaneously and read up on how staggered Animations should be capable of doing this. However, I was unable to understand the documentation for it and was looking for help.

Please guide me on how to do this using a single animation controller and tweens

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this kind of simultaneous animation you can use [flutter_sequence_animation](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sequence_animation).

> - No need to use intervals and calculate percentages for your total animation time.
> - Animate the same variable with multiple animatables!
> - You only need one AnimationController
> - Intuitive and easy to use interface

specify a sequence of animatables like this:

```
controller = AnimationController(vsync: this);
sequenceAnimation = SequenceAnimationBuilder()
    .addAnimatable(
        animatable: Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0),
        from: Duration.zero,
        to: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
        curve: Curves.ease,
        tag: "opacity")
    .addAnimatable(
        animatable: Tween<double>(begin: 50.0, end: 150.0),
        from: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
        to: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        curve: Curves.ease,
        tag: "width")
    .addAnimatable(
      animatable: ColorTween(
        begin: Colors.indigo[100],
        end: Colors.orange[400],
      ),
      from: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
      to: const Duration(milliseconds: 1500),
      curve: Curves.ease,
      tag: "color",
    )
    .animate(controller);
```

usage of sequenceAnimation:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
  child: Opacity(
    opacity: sequenceAnimation["opacity"].value,
    child: Container(
      width: sequenceAnimation["width"].value,
      height: 200,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: sequenceAnimation["color"].value,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

[demo simultaneous animation gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UoaY.gif)

[demo sequential animation gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVx8m.gif)

A working example:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
 // create variables
 late AnimationController animationController;

 late Animation<Offset> animationTranslate;
 late Animation<Offset> animationResize;
 late Animation<double> animationRotate;

 Offset containerSizeBegin = const Offset(50, 50);
 Offset containerSizeEnd = const Offset(100, 100);

 Offset containerPositionBegin = Offset.zero;
 Offset containerPositionEnd = const Offset(0, -200);// move the container upward 200 logical pixel
 
 double containerAngleBegin = 0;
 double containerAngleEnd = 6.28319;// 6.28319 radians equals 360 degrees

 @override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();
  // create an AnimationController that manages all of the Animations
  animationController = AnimationController(
   vsync: this,
   duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1500),// animation should last for 1.5 second
  );
  animationController.addStatusListener((status) {
   // animate container to original size, angle & position
   if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
    animationController.reverse();
   }
  });

  // translate tween
  animationTranslate = Tween<Offset>(
   begin: containerPositionBegin,
   end: containerPositionEnd,
  ).animate(animationController);
  // resize tween
  animationResize = Tween<Offset>(
   begin: containerSizeBegin,
   end: containerSizeEnd,
  ).animate(animationController);
  // rotation tween
  animationRotate = Tween<double>(
   begin: containerAngleBegin,
   end: containerAngleEnd,
  ).animate(animationController);
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
   body: Stack(
    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
    children: <Widget>[
      // animated object ---------------------------------------------------
      AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: animationController,
        child: _createSquareCenter(
          width: containerSizeBegin.dx,
          height: containerSizeBegin.dy,
        ),
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
          // resize the square
          var animatedChild = _createSquareCenter(
            width: animationResize.value.dx,
            height: animationResize.value.dy,
          );
          // translate the square
          animatedChild = Transform.translate(
            child: animatedChild,
            offset: animationTranslate.value,
          );

          // rotate the square around its center
          animatedChild = Transform.rotate(
            origin: animationTranslate.value,
            angle: animationRotate.value,
            child: animatedChild,
          );

          return animatedChild;
        },
      ),

      // user input --------------------------------------------------------
      TextButton(
        onPressed: () {
          // start animation
          animationController.forward();
        },
        child:
          Text(
            'Simultaneous Animation',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        style:
          ButtonStyle(
            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.indigo.shade400),
            padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(EdgeInsets.all(15)),
          ),
       ),
     ],
   ),
 );
}

Widget _createSquareCenter({required double width, required double height})  {
 return
  Center(
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.grey,
      width: width,
      height: height,
    ),
   );
  }
}
```

if you want sequential animation, use the code below to initialize tween

```
// run translate animation for the first 30% of the animationController's duration
animationTranslate = Tween<Offset>(
  begin: containerPositionBegin,
  end: containerPositionEnd,
).animate(
  CurvedAnimation(
    parent: animationController,
    curve: Interval(
      .0, .3,
    ),
  ),
);
// run resize animation for the second 30% of the animationController's duration
animationResize = Tween<Offset>(
  begin: containerSizeBegin,
  end: containerSizeEnd,
).animate(
  CurvedAnimation(
    parent: animationController,
    curve: Interval(
      .3, .6,
      curve: Curves.easeInOut,// animation easing curves
    ),
  ),
);
// run rotate animation for the last 40% of the animationController's duration
animationRotate = Tween<double>(
  begin: containerAngleBegin,
  end: containerAngleEnd,
).animate(
  CurvedAnimation(
    parent: animationController,
    curve: Interval(
      .6, 1,
      curve: Curves.bounceInOut,// animation easing curves
    ),
  ),
);
```